# Where can I find professional trainers who give me lessons?

Tags: battlefield-2

I am looking for good players who can train me and my friends in online multiplayer games. In particular Battlefield 2.

Is there a place where I can find a coach that can give us lessons?

Comment: Have you tried a few progamer's websites? Usually they offer such a service for pay -- [example](http://www.stermy.com/lessons.php).

Comment: @badp: Your comment is a better answer than the answers.

Comment: @Tim Fine, made it into an answer

Answer (score 5):

To be honest, since actual skill can't be taught but it rather comes with play time, the best advice I could give anyone in regards to online gaming is **PLAY FAIR !**. Some other basic guidelines my old clan (we were a bunch of real-life friends, from the same city) was very strict about:

- DO NOT CHEAT. EVER. PERIOD. It doesn't matter how much you suck, just don't do it. Every player sucked at first -- in fact, my own clan was named THC for Trigga Happy Crew, making fun of ourselves for the inability of shooting ... well ... anything. 6 to 8 months later, the situation completely reversed, and 90% of the time the first 6-8 players in a round were THC members, and having our squad score more points in a round than the whole opposite team altogether wasn't uncommon.
- Do not destroy your team's assets on purpose, be it vehicles or your team mates themselves. An extra "lame point" is awarded if the target just took "*your*" vehicle.
- DO NOT, EVER baserape. Attacking uncappable flags (i.e. MEC Airport or USMC Carrier on Gulf of Oman) is useless and one needs no skill whatsoever to get cheap kills by shooting people when they're disoriented after spawning. Includes but not limited to Artillery, SU-34 bombing, etc.
- Do not get in helicopters or airplanes if you can't fly. You'll prevent your team from winning when there are people who could actually make good use of those vehicles. Best way to train is in single player mode. Also if you're the pilot and you've got passengers, don't just jump off because "that's where you get off" -- do your job and fly them around, cap flags, etc.
- **TEAMPLAY !**

  - Communication - If you say you have a few buddies you're playing with, definitely use the built-in voice chat or other alternatives like Teamspeak or Ventrilo.
  - Kit coordination - Coordinate with each other and pack the right kits. 6 snipers will get pwned like there's no tomorrow against a tank or APC, whereas a team composed of a Medic, Anti-Tank, Spec-Ops and Support will surely cause some damage. My PERSONAL opinion is that both the assault and the sniper kit are pretty useless, maybe except for the smoke grenade from the Assault kit, but people rarely seem to take advantage of it. The engineer one is only useful if you ride around in a vehicle, so if possible, pack as many of the first set of kits as possible. Also, it is generally a good idea for the medic to stand a bit behind, since that's your squad's lifeline and obviously he wouldn't be of much use if dead.
  - Attack coordination - Doesn't matter what kind of kit you're packing and neither does voice chatting with your friends if you're 6 people attacking 6 different flags. Stick together and spawn on your squad leader. Also bear in mind that taking a flag with a full squad would be 6 times faster than it would be doing it on your own.

  To sum it up, the vast majority of the players wouldn't have the slightest idea how to counter-act a well coordinated attack, and even if they did, they would need an equally coordinated squad to actually stand a chance.
- Last but not least, simply be nice. Don't swear like a foul-mouthed child, don't punish teamkills if it wasn't intentional, and say sorry if you're the one doing the accidental teamkill. Basically, just don't do anything you wouldn't like if it were done to you.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: I disagree that there aren't thing that can be taught which will help you get better at the game faster.  Now I appreciate the time you took to write out a decent answer, but I don't think you really answered his question.  If you didn't think skill could be taught perhaps you could indicate how playing more affects your skills or what things the person can learn.

Comment: If you disagree that skill can't be taught, by all means, please feel free to post an answer and share your own experience. I'm definitely not claiming that my answer is the ultimate guide to becoming "pro". Since I couldn't answer Cilvic's question directly, I thought it would be helpful to at least give him a starting point by outlining the two things I personally consider most important in becoming a better player -- fair-play and team-play. Oh, and thanks for the typo correction ! :)

Comment: -1. Baserape and Camping are viable tactics. Yes, they suck, but this is war. http://www.teamwarfare.com/forums/showthread.asp?forumid=117&threadid=325417

Comment: @George - Not sure how or why a forum post by some random dude is supposed to stand as argument for something that's very subjective to begin with, since I already mentioned that these are my *personal* opinions. And for the fun of it, here's a quote from a reply on that same thread: `I teamkill for s***s and giggles when I get bored, I also LOVE to camp the bejesus out of someone until they threaten my life... I love being a douchebag over the internet.`

Comment: @FreekOne Well, by some random dude, you mean 'me'. And unfortunately it's in forum post format because at the time I was writing for that site, that's all they had.

Comment: @George - Fair enough, but I'm not sure why one point makes all the other points invalid enough to downvote. Regardless tho, one can clearly see that the vast majority of people who replied to your article disagreed with you to various degrees as well, which kind of strengthens what I said, rather than supporting your statement. Nicely written tho, I'll give you that !

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to learn playing is to join a clan as a rookie. In that way you'll train regularly without paying (well, you have to pay your quota for renting the game server)

Answer (score 0):

...train? There are two things you need. One is the ability to control a character in a FPS (dodging, strafing, aiming, etc). If you can't do that, the only way to get better is practice.

The second thing is learning how to play a particular game. Again practice is the main thing, although you can google for tips and tactics on a specific game. I can't even begin to count how many playing guides there are for Battlefield 2 for example. Hell, a lot of them are even YouTube videos so you don't even have to read anything and you can watch exactly how seasoned players go at it.

I understand that it sucks getting killed all the time, but you either get a sense of humor about it or you move on to something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to cough up some bucks, some progamers will gladly spend some time with you or your clan. After all, making a buck is the whole point of *professional* gaming.

If you're into seeing casts of (say) BF2 being  played at the highest levels, you will most likely know the nicks of people who probably have something like this already set up. [Here's the one example I know of.](http://www.stermy.com/lessons.php)

Just keep in mind that, while playing for a couple hours with a world class players is certainly bound to help you and inspire you, it's still no replacement for clocking in the thousands of hours that you need to actually get *good* at anything at all in life.

Comment: Thought I'd mention, I'm not affiliated with Stermy outside a short 5 minute chat with him over IRC.